# malloc() : memory corruption even if i check result of memory allocation function

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following code in my project:

```
static int* simpleRoute (int* initialRoute, int n, int i, int k) {
    int* newRoute = (int*)malloc(n);
    if (!newRoute) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        newRoute[j] = initialRoute[j];
    }
    for (int j = i; j < k+1; j++) {
        newRoute[j] = initialRoute[j];
    }
    for (int j = k+1; j < n; j++) {
        newRoute[j] = initialRoute[j];
    }
    return newRoute;
}
```

I keep having this error:

```
0 0x7ffff7a43428    __GI_raise(sig=sig@entry=6) (../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54)
1 0x7ffff7a4502a    __GI_abort() (abort.c:89)
2 0x7ffff7a857ea    __libc_message(do_abort=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b9e2e0 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") (../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175)
3 ??    0x00007ffff7a8f81e in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=0x7ffff7dd1b20 <main_arena>, ptr=0x609370, str=0x7ffff7b9b142 "malloc(): memory corruption", action=<optimized out>) (malloc.c:5004)
4 ??    _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7dd1b20 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=4) (malloc.c:3472)
5 0x7ffff7a915d4    __GI___libc_malloc(bytes=4) (malloc.c:2911)
6 0x40338b  simpleRoute(graphe=0x609580, initialRoute=0x609350, i=6, k=1) 
7 0x403522  opt2Simple(graphe=0x609580)
8 0x404b60  main()
```

I'm not sure what cause this error, any help?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I just made a tag edit which concurred with another simultaneous edit editing the code sample (~same second or so) and it merged the edits. Can I confirm that @Meryem made the code edit?

Comment: You write out of bounds - you malloc `n` bytes but then you write up to `n` ints into the space. An int takes up more than 1 byte

Comment: `int* newRoute = (int*)malloc(n);` requires that `n` is a multiple of `sizeof (int)`. Change it to `int* newRoute = malloc(n * sizeof (int));` And no need to cast malloc.

Comment: What is `n`?  It has to be a multiple of sizeof(int) in order for the code to work.  If `n` supposed to be maximum index, the code should be `int *newRoute = malloc(n*sizeof(*newRoute))`.

Comment: For this code to work, this criteria must hold : ` i <=n,  k+1<=n`.

Comment: `valgrind` is your friend when you have memory issues

Comment: @LambdaNinja yes it was me

Comment: @Nguaial I have tried both things and i still get the same error, I have used just (int*)malloc(n); in another part of my code for another variable and it worked just fine, I have a problem with just this part

Comment: @alvits I have tried that and i still get the same error, I have used just (int*)malloc(n); in another part of my code for another variable and it worked just fine, I have a problem with just this part

Comment: @Ôrel I ran it and it says 0 errors from 0 contexts

Comment: Just because it worked in another block of code doesn't make it right. You are invoking undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is just that, undefined. Sometimes it will work, other times it won't work. Until you fix all those wrong codes, you will keep seeing undefined behavior. Good luck.

Comment: `memory corruption` is already telling you that something else has written to the area that malloc is supposed to allocate. Could be that other block is writing past the allocated memory, cause that's what your code does.

Comment: I cannot believe you don't get `Invalid write of size 4` or similar with `valgrind`

Answer (score 3):

You allocate `n` bytes but you want to allocate space for `n` `int`s. An `int` is (usually) more than one byte.

Change `malloc(n)` to `malloc(n*sizeof(int))`.

(Also, `(int*)` is unnecessary)

Comment: I have tried that and i still get the same error, I have used just `(int*)malloc(n);` in another part of my code for another variable and it worked just fine, I have a problem with just this part

Comment: @Meryem Well then that other part of your code is wrong too.